# Не срабатывает роут

Tags: route, php, маршрутизация, kohana

```
Route::set('request','(<controller>(/<action>(/<mod>(/<id>))))',
    array(
        'mod'=>('change|notify')
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'objects',
        'action' => 'modify',
    ));
```

Ссылка такая:

```
http://site.com/objects/objects-list/change/1
```

В контроллере:

```
Сlass Controller_Objects extends Controller_DefaultTemplate {

    public function action_index() {

    }
    public function action_modify()
    {
        echo "<h1>1test</h1>";
    }

}
```

В `action`->modify я явно не попадаю, т.к. страница просто перезагружается, ошибок тоже никаких при этом нету (о том что роут неправильный), что может тут быть не так?

`kohana 3.2`

**Обновился**

Сделал вот такой роут:

```
Route::set('request','(<controller>(/<item>(/<action>(/<id>))))',
    array(
        'item'=>('objects-list'),
        'action'=>('change|notify')
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'objects',
        'action' => 'modify',
    ));
```

Так тоже не могу попасть, вернее оно то попадает в `action`->modify, но по такой ссылке:

```
http://site.com/objects/objects-list
```

**Решение**

В общем понял что переборщил с универсализацией, прописал точный роут:

```
Route::set('request','(objects/objects-list/<mod>(/<id>))',
    array(
        'mod'=>('change|notify')
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'objects',
        'action' => 'modify',
    ));
```

Comment: Это не касается вопроса. Но: который раз замечаю, что kohana хороший фреймворк!

Comment: @exec, а я и не отрицал никогда. @Xedelweiss, нет, я его еще потом дорабатывать буду, спасибо что подсказали!

Comment: @Maris, как неловко получилось - перенес свой коммент в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Первое.** В `Controller_Objects::action_modify()` вы и не должны попасть, т.к. в роуте у вас указано переопределение action'а.
По ссылке `http://site.com/objects/objects-list/change/1` значение `action = objects-list`

Зайдите на `http://site.com/objects/modify/change/1`

Вам действительно нужен универсальный шаблон для этого маршрута?

**Второе.** Маска для `mod` указана неправильно.

```
array(
    'mod' => '(change|notify)'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проще было с роутами - разберитесь с HMVC.
Kohana использует underscore в именовании классов и контроллеров, каждый такой underscore(нижнее подчёркивание) это слэш в файловой системе.
Как показывает практика, роута

```
Route::set('request','(<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))',
    array('id' => '[0-9]+'
)
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'default_directory',
    'controller' => 'default_controller',
    'action' => 'default_action',
));
```

Хватает на всё! Просто нужно грамотно организовывать свои файлы.
Приведу пример, думаю Вам станет понятнее о чём говорю:
uri: `directory/default_controller/action/id`
соответствует файлу `APPPATH.'/directory/default/controller'` в котором есть публичный метод action_action() и названию контроллера `Controller_Default_controller`.

Если что-то ещё не понятно - задавайте вопросы. С радостью отвечу.

Comment: у меня `underscores` переделаны под `dashes`, одним словом может быть и такой `action`->action_my_test_action

Comment: мсье знает толк в извращениях...